# Feasibility of TDOA localization with a single moving receiver and stationary source

Tags: cross-correlation, localization

Every paper/article I've read on the subject of TDOA localization is concerned with some combination of 2+ stationary receivers (or, sometimes, 1 stationary + 1 moving). There are also some papers that employ combinations of 1 moving receiver and several stationary reflectors with modifications to the algorithm.

What I'm looking for is an exploration of the following conditions:

- single source, decently powered (think a frequency jammer)
- single moving receiver

"Classical" TDOA for 3 receivers as far as I got it boils down to

- measuring 3 "copies" of the signal at the same time T (assuming the clock sync issue solved)
- calculating their cross-correlation

Would it be possible to do this instead?

- measure the signal at times t0, t1, t2
- [here's where by big theoretical/practical gap is] do some magic
- calculate their cross-correlation

An obvious issue would be that if the signal "shape" is periodic (e.g. pulsating in whatever form), I would have to "align" them which sounds like a manipulation that possibly defeats the whole idea? Apologies for the hand-waving, I'm really new to this area.

I would appreciate the explanation on why this is impossible and what modifications to the algorithm and/or receiver configuration should I have to do in order to be able to geolocate a transmitter.

I will also gladly accept any other ideas/hints that work for these constraints (single non-complicated receiver in hardware, any amount of time/power for pre/post-processing etc etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

It's *theoretically* possible, in that if you're in the world of theory where "$\cos \omega t$" *over here in my receiver, right now* means the same when "right now" turns to "a bit later", and when "in my receiver" turns to "in that transmitter".  In practice, I believe this will often be a deal-killer.

Basically, it requires that the source signal you're looking at have a structure that lets you reliably determine the lag between your measurements, and that the time base in your receiver is steady enough not to introduce significant errors.  This means that your equipment, and the signal you're trying to locate, both need to have very steady timebases.

Ultimately, the accuracy of the location will depend on the distance between your measurements and the accuracy of your measurement of the time-of-arrival differences, themselves translated into distances.  Longer baselines means more accurate final position determination for a given time-of-arrival accuracy, but if you're doing this with one antenna moving around, it also means less accurate time-of-arrival measurements.

Since you can make fairly compact *directional* antennas (some of the popular ones use TDOA techniques, even), then if you're going to have moving antennas it may be better to get bearings at your different locations, and triangulate.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I'm still not clear on whether trying to cross-correlate signals from different "time slices" makes theoretical sense but your suggestion about triangulation is something I can work with. Thank you!

Comment: It might be possible for a signal designed to facilitate the method. You would need it to be repetitive with jitter less than the desired distance estimation precision and be suitable for cross correlation (like a chirp vs. unmodulated carrier). In the wild, you'd be better off taking successive bearings using pseudo-doppler or correlative phase interferometry, where a single receiver system can determine the bearing. Look up KrakenSDR for an example of the latter.

Comment: @Deepstop: I had considered that, but the question posits looking for a jammer -- I would assume that a halfway self-respecting jamming signal would try to _not_ facilitate this method (or any other, for that matter).

Comment: Exactly. I'm looking at multiple receivers here. Being mostly for repeater jamming, I'm hoping we can use the repeater output signal as a time reference and not need GPS timing. any problems to solve before we can validate that approach.

Comment: @Deepstop: it looks like you're opening a new topic.  Welcome to Stackexchange, where we do things a little bit differently.  If you have a question to ask **start a new question**.  Make sure that it's closed-ended (i.e., not a discussion-starter), and hopefully you'll get some nice answers that are specific to the question you have asked.